# Meaning of "+" or "-" in nohup messages

Tags: bash, nohup

When a command with nohup like:

```
nohup python [program name] > result_logs &
```

is done, some prompt will come out like:

```
[1]  - [process_id] done       nohup [program name] >result_logs
```

But I don't quite understand the meaning of the sign '-' here, sometimes it comes with '+' like:

```
[1]  + [process_id] done       nohup [program name] >result_logs
```

Anyone knows the meaning of this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`-` means previous job, `+` means current job

From `man bash` (Section `JOB CONTROL`):

> There are a number of ways to refer to a job in the shell.  The character % introduces a job specification (jobspec).  Job number n may be referred  to  as
>          %n.   A  job  may also be referred to using a prefix of the name used to start it, or using a substring that appears in its command line.  For example, %ce
>          refers to a stopped ce job.  If a prefix matches more than one job, bash reports an error.  Using %?ce, on the other hand, refers to any job containing the
>          string  ce  in  its command line.  If the substring matches more than one job, bash reports an error.  The symbols %% and %+ refer to the shell's notion of
>          the current job, which is the last job stopped while it was in the foreground or started in the background.  The previous job may be referenced  using  %-.
>          If  there  is only a single job, %+ and %- can both be used to refer to that job.  **In output pertaining to jobs (e.g., the output of the jobs command), the
>          current job is always flagged with a +, and the previous job with a -.**  A single % (with no accompanying job specification) also refers to the current job.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, this is about bash (I'm referring to your flag). Nevertheless, it's on topic here and not on topic on SO since it isn't about programming but about bash's job control.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! At the end, 5 ups here aren't bad as well :)